# looking for similar data with like

Tags: codeigniter

In my controller, I send a string to my model. when I send that, the string is encoded and it makes problem in my query because I use LIKE Operator.

controller :

`$this->base_model->get_post('football');`

model:

```
function get_post($string){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('title' , $string , 'both');
$query = $this->db->get('post');
return $query->result();
}
```

In the model when I echo the $string it becomes to `%D9%81%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84` not `football` so the query can't fetch any data from my database

Comment: Have you tried this? `$value = 'football'; $this->base_model->get_post($value);`

Comment: yes but it would get encode again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode it.

```
function get_post($string){
   $decrypt = $this->encryption->decode($string);
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->like('title' , $decrypt , 'both');
   $query = $this->db->get('post');
   return $query->result();
}
```